# dimensions of a tensor product operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, tensor-calculus

I would like to solve the following Task. Consider the states

$|\psi_1\rangle=\cos(\Theta_1/2)|0\rangle+\sin(\Theta_1/2)e^{i \phi_1}|1\rangle$

$|\psi_2\rangle=\cos(\Theta_2/2)|0\rangle+\sin(\Theta_2/2)e^{i \phi_2}|1\rangle$

$|\phi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(|0\rangle+ |1\rangle+ |2\rangle)$

and the operator $P_0$ acting in the hilbert space $\mathbb{C^3}\bigotimes\mathbb{C^4}$

$P_0=|0\rangle\langle 0| \bigotimes(|1\rangle \bigotimes |0\rangle\langle1| \bigotimes \langle0|)$.

Now, calculate the probability

$p_0=(\langle \phi|\bigotimes \langle \psi |)P_0(|\phi\rangle \bigotimes |\psi\rangle)$ with $|\psi\rangle=|\psi_1\rangle \bigotimes |\psi_2\rangle$.

The Point is, I don't know how to apply $P_0$ on $(|\phi\rangle \bigotimes |\psi\rangle$.

How does $(|1\rangle \bigotimes |0\rangle\langle1| \bigotimes \langle0|)$ act on $|\psi_1\rangle \bigotimes |\psi_2\rangle$?
Those three tensor products are confusing me. So far, I have only seen operators where the number of tensor products in the operator is the same as the number of tensor products in the state it is acting on.

I know how to calculate it in matrix representation, but I don't know how to solve this with dirac-notation. How does this work?

Btw how do you find out in this case what the dimensions of the mapping $P_0$ are? I know it is mapping from $\mathbb{C^4}\rightarrow \mathbb{C^4}$, but how do find this out in a mathematically correct way?

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, forget the operator for a second. Do you know how to act with $(\langle 1 | \otimes \langle 0 |)$ on $|\psi_1 \rangle \otimes |\psi_2 \rangle$? That's all you need to know.

Comment: yes, i know how this is done. But I don't see how this could help me

Comment: This quantity is a number. Then $|1 \rangle \otimes |0 \rangle$ acts on this number. That's it!

Comment: but doesn't it make a difference if it's $(|0\rangle \otimes |1\rangle)(\langle 0| \otimes \langle1 |)$ or $(|0\rangle \otimes |1\rangle\langle 0| \otimes \langle1 |)$? (the difference are the parentheses)

Comment: okay, but in my task it says $(|0\rangle \otimes |1\rangle\langle 0| \otimes \langle1 |)$. btw why is this 1?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the comment. The lack of parentheses just means your problem writer was being sloppy.

Comment: oh ok, so this means that formally without the parentheses it does not make any sense?

Comment: It _can_ make sense. The quantity $|0 \rangle \otimes |1 \rangle \langle 0 | \otimes \langle 1|$ lies in the space $V \otimes W \otimes W^* \otimes V^*$, which is isomorphic to $(V \otimes W) \otimes (V \otimes W)^*$, which is the space of linear operators that $P$ should be in.

Comment: However, this is a really bad way of writing it, because in your current notation, it's ambiguous which thing belongs to which space. (i.e. is the first $|0\rangle$ in $\mathbb{C}^3$, or is it in $\mathbb{C}^4$?) To avoid this ambiguity we usually write things 'in order', so that everything involved looks like $(|v\rangle \otimes |w \rangle)$ where $v \in V$ and $w \in W$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45222/discussion-between-user9996-and-knzhou).